# Correct stripe with for RAID-50

Tags: raid

I've been trying to determine what the correct stripe width for a RAID-50 volume is but haven't been successful in google searches or empirical tests. The volume is built off of 4 disk spans that contain 6 disks each. If I understand it correctly, each individual span is a RAID-5 volume and the 4 spans are combined using RAID-0. However, I'm not seeing any noticable effect when I vary the stripe-width from 2-20. Suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What do you expect? And why do you even care about stripe widths?

Comment: R50? was R10 too fast and effective for you?

Comment: @Chopper3 He wants to save disc capacity. That's OK.

Comment: Why not just go RAID 6?

Comment: @mailq: No it isn't.  Disks are cheap.  If you need more capacity, buy more disks.  RAID-50 is an unacceptable risk.

Comment: @mailq The chassis has 24 disks, would like to keep capacity high. One of our admins does not like the idea of a single RAID set that is 24 disks wide, but seemed okay with this option. I'm concerned about stripe-width as my understanding is that it can effect filesystem performance if it is not specified correctly.

Comment: @wombie: disks are cheap but administration/personal is expensive. Mo disk mo problems.

Comment: @Chopper3 the stripe width question is still relevant unless I'm absolutely naive (which is a realistic possibility)

Comment: @Chopper3, I'm only loosing 4 disks in the current configuration. I'm not asking how to pick stripe width, I'm asking how to determine it. In RAID5 it is easy as it is just n-1. What is it in RAID50?

Comment: What controller are you using?

Comment: Intel RAID RS2MB044

Comment: @womble: if your controller/enclosure cannot handle more than a given amount of disks, adding more disks is rather expensive.

Answer (score 2):

While I realize that this is over a year old, I recently ran into the same question and came to a different conclusion and wanted to add it for posterity.

Unfortunately I think the FusionIO article mentioned here may be wrong. First, their table shows that to find the number of data bearing disks on a raid50 you take the number of "mirrored_sets" and subtract one. However it also has this text near the table:

> - mirrored_sets = The number of raid 1 mirrored sets that are used to form the higher- level group

The problem is that raid50 doesn't have any "raid 1 mirrored sets", and the whole idea just sounds kind of, funny.

The larger reason though is that I came across a more recent thread that included input from an ext guru (Andreas Dilger). The explanation on that thread made a lot more sense to me, even before considering reputation.

You can find that [here](http://www.redhat.com/archives/ext3-users/2012-June/msg00002.html), but I'm going to paste the key part below for good measure...

```
>> DS: Based on my understanding of what stride and stripe-width set,
>> it seems to me that it should be calculated the same as it would
>> be if there were no multiple-level RAIDing involved.  For example,
>> given a RAID 50 made up of two 3+1 RAID 5s striped together (so 8
>> disks total) with a 512k chunk size and 4k block size, the stride
>> should be 128 (512 / 4) and the stripe-width should be 768
>> (stride * 6 data disks).
>
> AD: Strictly speaking, you only need a stripe-width of 384 (stride * 3
> data disks) since this is the minimum read-modify-write boundary.

Ah, right.  Thanks, I was over-thinking it.
```

HTH,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

After digging around online, I found this line (http://kb.fusionio.com/KB/a43/filesystem-tuning.aspx) that indicated the stripe width in nested RAID levels should be based on the number of spans/groups. In my case, as I have 4 spans in RAID50, the stripe width (as used in XFS), is 3 (n-1, where n is the number of spans)